# What is a term for an OS command?

Tags: command-line, terminology

What is a name denoting something which executes (normally in a separate address space), accepts an input, generates output and exit code?

I'd name this "Unix command", but there may be also say "Windows command"; I'd name it "shell command", but it may be no shell involved.

Comment: If there's no shell involved, what's launching it?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: an other program (using for example execve() Unix C function)

Comment: Can you give an example? What would another program launch that wouldn't be correctly described as a "shell command" that is covered by the scope of your question? (A car is a "car" if it's capable of powered movement, right? It doesn't stop being a car just because it's rolling down a hill.)

Comment: I'd call that an "application", or perhaps simply a "program".

Answer (score 3):

Program? Executable file?  Or, as you said, command.

Comment: Yep, this is just a "program".

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: But how to call a program together with arguments (like `xmllint --format file.xml`)?

Comment: That's a command line. (Or 'command'.)

Comment: Yeah, if you are, eg, telling someone how to do something, you might say "In the command window, enter the command 'xyz -abc C:\efg.txt'."

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a `program`.

If you pass something like what you mentioned, `xmllint --format file.xml`, then `xmllint` would be your program, `--format` would be your `[options]` and `file.xml` would be your `source file`.

**Eg**: `javac [ options ] [ sourcefiles ]`

Hope this helps!